# How can I add my own certificate (.pem file) to my selenium chromedriver?

Tags: java, selenium, ssl-certificate, selenium-chromedriver, pem

I have a docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
   services:
      selenium-3-chrome:
      image: selenium/standalone-chrome-debug:3.14.0
      restart: always
environment:
  TZ: Europe/Budapest
  SCREEN_WIDTH: 1920
  SCREEN_HEIGHT: 1080
  JAVA_OPTS: -Xmx128m
ports:
  - 4444:4444
  - 5900:5900
volumes:
  - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
```

My java code:

```
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = util.chromeOptions(scenario);
        chromeOptions.setHeadless(true);//default-bol is az
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--window-size=1366,768");

        DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        capability.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);

        initProperies();
        if(config == null) {
            readConfiguration();
            try {
                host = System.getProperty(HOSTNAME);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                 //...
            }
        }
        // itt állítom rá a docker-es chromedriverre:
        WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(config.getConnection().getWebDriverUrl()), capability);

        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(90000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        driver.get(host+"/");
```

How can I add my own certificate to capabilities or chromeOptions? "/home/../rootca/lbsca.pem" -> in the chrome browser, it is in the "Authorities" certs not in "your certificates". Or it's possible that I can add my .pem to the docker's standalone-chrome?
I hope, i was understanding.. Sorry for my english

Comment: Better to use an existing browser profile where the pem file is imported.

Comment: Is it a must to add certificate? Or if you can skip the certificate control and it will work for you?

Comment: Sadly, the certificate is must have to images downloading to the page, outer files downloading (example: javasrcipt files, etc), so all that is not static :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PhantomJSDriver can be used to perform this functionality.

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
ImmutableMap<String, String> commandLineArguments = ImmutableMap.<String, 
String>builder()
    .put("web-security", "false")
    .put("ssl-protocol", "any")
    .put("ignore-ssl-errors", "true")
    .put("webdriver-loglevel", "DEBUG")
    .put("ssl-client-certificate-file", certificatePath)
    .put("ssl-client-key-passphrase", certificatePassword)
    .build();
String[] params = commandLineArguments.entrySet().stream()
    .map(e -> String.format("--%s=%s", e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
    .toArray(new String[0]);
cap.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, params);
cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(cap);
driver.get(Url);
```

---

If the certificate is not a must that means you can skip certificate control by accepting  unsecured certificates, you can skip the certificate control with the following capabilities:

**Chrome & Internet Explorer**

```
capability.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
capability.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_INSECURE_CERTS, true)
```

**Firefox**

First you need to a create profile, let's say `exampleProfile`.
Then, access to that profile in your script with the code below;

```
ProfilesIni profIni = new ProfilesIni();        
FirefoxProfile exampleProfile = profIni.getProfile("exampleProfile");
```

After that, you need to set `AcceptUntrustedCertificates` & `AssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer` properties.

```
exampleProfile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
exampleProfile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);
```

Finally, you can initialize your driver with the following code below;

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(exampleProfile);
```